# How to load local HTML file in WKWebView when developing an iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, wkwebview

I developed an iOS framework that users can use with CocoaPod. But when using it in a project, there is an error on this line:

```
let url = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "file_name", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "assets")!
```

This line is in the framework and the error is:

```
Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In the framework, I have a folder named "assets" and a file named "file_name.html". The error happens only when it is used in a framework.

Comment: You want to use "file_name.html" from assets directory inside a framework in your main project. is that right?

Comment: To be clear, the framework has a UIVIewController (containing a WKWebView) that I want to use in my main project. All code related to the WebView is in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let url = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "file_name", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "assets")!
-------------------------------^
```

Make sure that `self` points to a class of the framework in order to find the right bundle. And you don't need to use `type(of:_)`:

```swift
let bundle = Bundle(for: FrameworkClass.self)
let url = bundle.url(forResource: "file_name", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "assets")!
```

Comment: Do I need to add my assets folder in spec.resources in the CocoaPod spec file?

Comment: I had to add it to the cocoa pod file to make it work: 
`s.resources = ['assets/*']`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "file_name.html" is missing in your Cocoapod framework. Please add it something like below in your podspec.

```
   s.resource_bundles = {
    'ResourceBundleName' => ['path/to/resources/Assets/*']
   }
   s.resources = "ResourceBundleName/**/*.{html,icon}"
```

Your code seems to be absolutely fine when i added it in one of the functions of my sample Framework project. No compilation error.

You can also use following code inside your pod to access the resource.

```
  let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
  let bundleURL = frameworkBundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("FrameworkName.bundle")
  let resourceBundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL!)
  let url = resourceBundle?.url(forResource: "file_name", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "assets")!
```

Please see this link for more info on how to access resource from Framework: "https://useyourloaf.com/blog/loading-resources-from-a-framework/". Thought it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Do I always use /**/* in the s.resources?

Comment: Yes, please check cocoapods document here: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html

Comment: After updating the podSpec and doing "pod install", are you seeing your assets inside your downloaded framework?

Comment: Can you please paste the snapshot of your app bundle with assets inside your framework?

Comment: It's the same error but now in a line from my project not the framework. Here is the line:  present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191272/discussion-between-anand-and-tsil).

Comment: @tsil, are you able to resolve the issue after removing "assets" from framework?